# How to retrieve journals list for a particular subject classification category using Scopus Serial Title API?

Tags: scopus

Scopus Serial API allows to retrieve titles for a particular classification category by a `subj` parameter. For instance, when I specify `subj=COMP&content=journal`, I get all the journals in a category `"Computer Science (all)"`, `abbrev=COMP`, `code=1700`.

However, in this list, there are only journals with `code=1700` and the journals from Computer Science sub-categories are missing. How do I get journals, e.g., for a sub-category `"Computer Science (Software)"` that has `code=1712` and the same `abbrev=COMP`?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in the API. According to the Scopus Source Title list (https://www.elsevier.com/?a=91122), there are over 2,000 titles in Computer Science; and according to the Scopus Subject Classification API (https://dev.elsevier.com/documentation/SubjectClassificationsAPI.wadl), they all should have the 'COMP' abbreviation (even if they have different sub-classifications, i.e. 17xx codes). But when calling the Scopus Serial API as in your example (https://api.elsevier.com/content/serial/title?subj=COMP), there seem to be at most 330 or so journal records that can be retrieved. We'll report this to our development group.

Comment: Please be careful with linking to your own content on different sites, you don't want to be a [spammer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). You should be including the majority of the content here, and use the link only as a reference.

Comment: @Dharman that's exactly what we did here. The substance of the answer is here, and the links only exist to allow the user to validate the answer by looking at the primary sources him/herself. Also, in this case, it is not practical to replicate the source content, as the first link points to an Excel file, the second link points to an auto-generated API spec, and the third link points to an API endpoint (not to a content page). But thanks for the warning.

Comment: No problem. Linking to a downloadable file is very suspicious and raises red flags when combined with a domain that matches the username. I didn't flag this answer as spam, but I was close to doing it, which is why I warned in the comments instead.